# f2py: command not found

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, f2py

Mac OS Sierra.

In terminal, while trying to execute a `.sh` file that involves a Python script with Fortran portions, I got this message:

```
lenscov-master Roger$ ./run_covariances.sh recompile
rm *.o *.so
rm: *.so: No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)
gfortran -fPIC -c *.f -lgfortran -lifcore
f2py-2.7 -c loop_lensing.f90 *.o -m loop_lensing --opt=-ffixed-line-length-
none --opt=-O3
/bin/sh: f2py-2.7: command not found
make: *** [loop_lensing] Error 127
```

However, it is fine just test-running the `.f90` file:

```
f2py -c loop_lensing.F90 -m test
```

returns a bunch of normal-looking information.

Does anyone maybe know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is fine just test-running the .f90 file

means you have `f2py` installed. But the script use f2py-2.7

You need to check the version of installed `f2py`, and make sure `f2py-2.7` redirects to the corrent `f2py`.

Answer (score 1):

The script (or a Makefile) tries to invoke `f2py-2.7` instead of `f2py`. If it is your script or you can easily adjust it, rename all `f2py-2.7` to `f2py`. Otherwise you have to tell us more about the script and show the code of the script.

As foodtooth says, make sure you have f2py 2.7 and not f2py-3, but I don't expect that to be a problem.

You could also make a symlink f2py -> f2py-2.7 for the script.